# Problem during creating jar with jnativehook library Maven JAR

Tags: java, maven, jar, jnativehook

Currently, I make a simple clicker in java. I liked the library `jnativehook`, because it's working in the background and I added it as a dependency

```
<dependency>
    <artifactId>jnativehook</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.1stleg</groupId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

Compilation ended successfully and IDE had no warning
but after running JAR with terminal

`java -jar clicker.jar`

I had the following error

```
C:\Users\szymo\IdeaProjects\java gui\target>java -jar clicker-javagui-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Error: Unable to initialize main class Main

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jnativehook/NativeHookException
```

I suspect that it's a problem with compiling the library to jar. I tried also adding `jnativehook.jar` to classpath but it didn't help.

I use JDK 11, and Maven 3.6.3.

Comment: You need to use [maven shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to shade in JNativeHook

Comment: @Alfie Thanks I will try

Comment: @Alfie your way worked, i was looking for that answer almost half a week, thanks